# Error importing html.widgets of iPython in Canopy

Tags: python, plot, ipython, enthought, canopy

I am trying to run the following code from [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/widgets/Lorenz.ipynb):

```
from IPython.html.widgets import interact, interactive
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
----> 1 from IPython.html.widgets import  interactive


ImportError: No module named widgets
```

And I am using Canopy as IDE. Do I need to install an extra package to get this `widgets`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for using Canopy. IPython.html.widgets have been added in the 1.2.0 which was just out. Canopy will offer the update as soon as we will have a chance to test that the new version will work smoothly for you. It is likely to be available by mid-march. If you need to have it *now*, you can do the following:

1. Check out the project from github: `git clone git@github.com:ipython/ipython.git`
2. Grab the 1.2.0 release branch with `git checkout rel-1.2.0`
3. run `python setup.py develop` using your *Canopy* python executable.
4. Start the notebook from the terminal as opposed to the notebook inside Canopy so that your bleeding edge version is being used.

Comment: Is this supposed to be there now? I'm using Canopy 1.4 and theabove import still fails

Answer (score 3):

The version of IPython available from within Canopy's Python pane is currently hard set to 1.2.1 as of Canopy 1.4.1. However, users can update their IPython package to version 2.1.0 for use at the command line. Updating and launching IPython/Python from the command line (with Canopy set as the default, or from the Canopy Tools Menu > Canopy Command Prompt / Terminal) should give you access to `IPython.html.widgets`.

Please see this article for more information: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22305234-IPython-Installed-version-in-the-Package-Manager-is-not-being-used-in-the-Canopy-GUI